# Run jar file from swift application with nstask

Tags: java, macos, swift, jar, nstask

I'm trying to execute a jar file from my swift application. I use the code bellow:

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("MyJar", ofType: "jar")!

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/java"
task.arguments = ["-jar", path, arg]

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print(output)
```

It works well when i execute the application from xcode but when i launch the application from the app icon it doesn't work and i don't get why...

Edit :
So I've put some NSLog() into my code :

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("AudioTagger", ofType: "jar")!

NSLog("%@", "jar path : \(path)")

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/java"
task.arguments = ["-jar", path, xml]

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
let errorPipe = NSPipe()
task.standardError = errorPipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()

NSLog("%@", "Task is finished")

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let errorData = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let errorOutput: String = NSString(data: errorData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

NSLog("%@", output)
NSLog("%@", errorOutput)
```

And i get this into the console :

```
16:41:09 MyApp: jar path : /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fbeddkvghwjpjpgvrkrfzbjxjvse/Build/Products/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/MyJar.jar
16:41:09 MyApp: Task is finished
16:41:14 Console: Failed to connect (_consoleX) outlet from (NSApplication) to (ConsoleX): missing setter or instance variable
```

The standard error seems to be empty, so i still don't get it...

Comment: Your problem is perhaps only that the app has no standard output when launched from the Finder or Dock. Where did you expect to see the output of `print` ? Do you know if the Java task executed or not? Did you try to add more print statements to isolate the problem? – You could use NSLog() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have your jar in your `Bundle Resources`.

Because if you use the NSBundle, you need to have the Jar also in your `Bundle Resources`.

If you don't have it in there, you have to add the JAR in your Xcode target under `Build Phases` to `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Comment: Yes I already added my jar into my bundle resources, and i can see it into the resources folder of my .app

Comment: no there is no errors showing up because when i open my application in a terminal to see the standard output my application works well and i get no error. It's just when i open it from the app icon it doesn't work...

Comment: got any solution?